# What is the difference between service-cidr, and service-cluster-ip-range?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Being relatively new to Kubernetes, I am getting lost in Kubernetes and Azure's documentation. I can't find any clarification on what the difference between these two are:
**service-cidr** and **service-cluster-ip-range**

Also, do we need to set them if we are creating a production grade cluster?

The documentation for "service-cluster-ip-range" is from:
[kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)
Under the section "Choosing your own IP address"

Comment: could you please share the documentation regarding `service-cluster-ip-range` where this terminology is being used, 

`service-cidr` in the context of Azure Kubernetes service is the CIDR/IP Address range out of which the Kubernetes service object will get the IP.  yes it's needed to define this range by default AKS has  `10.0.0.0/16`  prefilled option.  Note from Azure docs: `This range shouldn't be used by any network element on or connected to this virtual network. Service address CIDR must be smaller than /12. You can reuse this range across different AKS clusters.`

Comment: @ishuar I have added the details for "service-cluster-ip-range" in my question

Comment: as per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#choosing-your-own-ip-address 

The IP address that you choose must be a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address from within the service-cluster-ip-range CIDR range that is configured for the API server. Here they are referring to basically the `service-cidr` input of the AKS resource. 

Long story short what I understood,  `service-cidr` and `service-cluster-ip-range` are the same in your case, one is using the AKS terminology and the other is the native Kubernetes. 

Yes its better to plan this range to avoid conflicts.

Comment: The kubernetes cluster kind of setup a virtual network. The ```service-CIDR``` is the optional field to set specifically the subnet within ```service-cluster-ip-range```